# Should Scrum methodology questions be in pm or programmers stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, support

Should questions relating to the scrum methodology be in pm or programmers stack exchange?

I can see arguments for both, but want to be sure to put my questions in the most useful place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Questions about Scrum, or any other development methodology or process, are [very much on-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Generally, if your question is about a software-intensive project, it's on-topic here.

You can browse through some related tags to see what kinds of questions have been asked here about things like [project management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bproject-management%5D+closed%3Ano+is%3Aquestion), [development processes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdevelopment-process%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) and [life cycle models](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blife-cycle%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) (specifically [Scrum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bscrum%5D%20closed:no%20is:question), [CMMI](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcmmi%5D%20closed:no%20is:question), [Rational Unified Process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brational-unified-process%5D%20closed:no%20is:question)) or [the agile methods](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bagile%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) in general, [project planning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bproject-planning%5D%20closed:no%20is:question), [estimation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bestimation%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) ([cost](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcost-estimation%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) and [time](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btime-estimation%5D%20closed:no%20is:question)) and [scheduling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bscheduling%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) and [software schedules](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware-schedules%5D%20closed:no%20is:question), and [measurement](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmeasurement%5D%20closed:no%20is:question) and [metrics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmetrics%5D%20closed:no%20is:question).

Some of these tags are also in use on Project Management - [development processes](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-process) ([Scrum](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum), [CMMI](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cmmi), [Rational Unified Process](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rup)) and [the agile methods](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile), [project planning](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning), [scheduling](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling), and [measurement](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) and [metrics](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics).

I'd recommend browsing those some of the questions on both sites and seeing how the questions are asked and the type of answers that are generated, since the community tends to be different (with some overlap).

You shouldn't cross-post questions between sites without tailoring them for the audience. If you do post a question and find you aren't getting answers or are getting answers that might not be what you're looking for, you can try to rephrase the question on the other site or flagging it and asking for moderator migration.

Personally, I'd like to see more software management, process, and professional practice questions here on Programmers since that's my area of expertise. But you should be asking on the site that you think will best give you the answers you need to solve your problems.

Answer (score 4):

Whichever you prefer.  It is on topic at both places.

The decision you make though is if you want an answer from a developer perspective or a project manager perspective.

Comment: Thanks. Is it bad etiquette to put it in both, if I want answers from both groups?

Comment: @SpoonerNZ Generally, you should avoid posting the same question on multiple sites. Try one of the sites first, and if you don't get satisfactory answers in a reasonable amount of time (a week?) then you have two options: 1) Flag the question and ask for it to be moved to the other site and 2) Repost the question to the other site. If you decide to go with option 2 (or your flag is declined) then it would be nice if you took some time to tailor the question to the second site's audience and not just repost it verbatim.